# Is there a way to get class constructor arguments by self inspection?

Tags: python, json, serialization, constructor

I have a set of classes that I want to serialize to/from both JSON and a mongodb database.  The most efficient way I see to do that is to write methods to serialize to dicts, then use built-in methods to get to/from storage. (**Q1: Is this conclusion actually valid, or is there a better way?**)

So, to export an instance of my class to a dict, I can use self.**dict**. In my case these classes get nested, so it has to be recursive, fine.  Now I want to read it back...but now I'm stuck if my class has a non trivial constructor. Consider:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value=None):
        self.name = name
        self._value = value
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

a = MyClass('spam', 42)
d = a.__dict__ #has {'name':'spam', '_value':42}
#now how to unserialize?
b = MyClass(**d) #nope, because '_value' is not a valid argument
c = MyClass(); c.__dict__.update(d)  #nope, can't construct 'empty' MyClass
```

I don't want to write a constructor that ignores unknown parameters, because I hate wasting hours trying to figure out why a class is ignoring some parameter to find that there was a typo in the name. And I don't want to remove the required parameters, because that may cause problems elsewhere.

So how do I get around this mess I've made for myself?

- If there's a way to bypass the class's constructor and create an empty 
  object, that might work, but if there is any useful work done in `__init__`, I lose that. (E.g. type/range checking of parameters).
- In my case, these classes don't change after construction (they define lots of useful methods, and have some caching).  So if I could extract just the constructor arguments from the dict, I'd be doing good. Is there a way to do that that doesn't involve repeating all the constructor arguments??

Comment: You’re better off creating factory methods for deserializing each type, so the type has actual control over how to construct the object. Otherwise, you’re just there on the outside, guessing how that black box type works as you attempt to fill in the right values. – Imagine if that `value` property returned `self._value * 2` instead.

Comment: Are you open to hacks like this: http://ideone.com/R9T2Nd ?

Comment: @poke I don't understand the last part of your comment; as long as the properties/methods don't mutate any attributes, why do I care about them for serialization?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Whoa. Overriding `__new__` is definitely not something I had thought of.  Even better would be to make it a decorator, and take the dictionary in the alternate constructor.  The key is the `object.__new__(cls)` .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's just a trivial example or not but I can't see the value of the property `value`(No pun intended). If you're directly assigning the value argument from the `__init__` I mean. In that case just using a simple attribute will solve your problem.

But if for some reason you really need a property just strip the dash in the key :

```
class MyClass(object): 
    Pdef __init__(self, name, value=None):
        self.name = name 
        self._value = value 
    @property 
    def value(self): 
        return self._value 

a = MyClass('spam', 42)
d = {k.strip('_'): v for k, v in a.__dict__.items()}
b = MyClass(**d)
```

Comment: value here is indeed a trivial example, although even this gives a somewhat useful "read-only" attribute.  The main point was that the constructor arguments don't all map directly onto "public" attributes with the same name. The trick of filtering the underscore might be simple enough for what I'm doing